# Implementing a polymorphic many-to-many relationship with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

How does one implement a many-to-many relationship in Mongoid?  For example, we have a **User**, which can have many **Notifications**, and **Notification** is the parent class for **SpecificNotification**.  Every **User** can be alerted to *N* **Notifications** (meaning both **Notifications**, **SpecificNotifications**) and every **Notification** (meaning both, again) can apply to *N* **Users**.

I tried the following:

### in user.rb:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :notifications
  attr_accessible :notifications, :notification_ids
end
```

### in notification.rb:

```
class Notification
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  attr_accessible :users, :user_ids
end
```

### in specificnotification.rb:

```
class SpecificNotification < Notification
  field :something_specific
end
```

But when I create a **SpecificNotification**, related **Users** aren't updated -- **Users** will only record **Notifications**, not **SpecificNotifications**.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer for your problem but here are **my 2 cents**:

I would suggest thinking in **denormalizing** your data model. On a social network that I have I had a fairly similar problem: users have many notifications and the same notification would go for a lot of users.

But instead of doing a many to many relationship, I went on a noSQL style and **replicated the notification on each user**. This way it was easier to customize the notifications with each user's name and other attributes too. I think that would be the "right way" to model it with mongodb.

Same goes for this specific field, as you are using mongoid, some objects may and may not have some fields. If there aren't a lot of types of notifications with lots of fields, maybe it would be better to just put that field on the Notification model.